# Web.go How can I do http redirections?

Tags: go

I am  writing a small app using web.go with a function that serves a form. If the form is not valid, user will be redirected to the same page:

```
func mypage(ctx *web.Context) {
     if ctx.Request.Method == "GET" {
         // show the form
     } else if ctx.Request.Method == "POST" {
        // redirection if the form is not valid:
        ctx.Request.Method = "GET"
        http.Redirect(ctx.ResponseWriter, 
                      ctx.Request, "/mypage", http.StatusNotAcceptable)
        return
     }
}
```

This works, with one caveat that when the form is not valid, it first shows a page with the text `"Not Acceptable"` that is liked to `/mypage`. How can I make it to go directly to `/mypage` in case the form is not valid? I suspect that it is related to `http.StatusNotAcceptable` but I don't know what I should replace it with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out it was easy :)

```
ctx.Request.Method = "GET"
mypage(ctx)
```

No need for `http.Redirect`. The important part is to change the `Method` to `GET` first, before calling `mypage(ctx)`.